# Azure SQL: Unexplainable Database size

Tags: azure-sql-database

Last month we upgraded our Azure database from Business to S1 plan. S1 plan was chosen based on an article on MSDN giving guidance on how to choose the best plan for us. Also, Azure by itself suggested to upgrade to S1.

However, after a week of usage we felt that S1 is low on power for our need, and it was way too slow for our, then, 1.5GB of database. Then we shifted to S2 plan as a test and immediately found that S2 is the right plan for us. All queries that on Business took <1 sec and were taking 20-30 sec on S1 are now taking <2 sec on S2.

We were happy, but now after one month our site that was < 1GB for 3-4 yrs and recently grew to 1.5GB and remained that size for 3-4 months is 4.5 GB. There is absolutely nothing changed from our side. The data we add is hardly 100MB this month. If we think of the space indexes take, even then 3GB increase in size is simply unanswerable to us.

We do not have big operation except that we upload CSV of 1000-10K records per day but that has been part of site for years. We delete these rows after a few days, so the database size remains constant.

**Is there any explanation for this?**

I tried Google and found nothing that can explain this growth. Growth is like 100-200 MB per day. Is it the logs taking space? If so how can I check, or reduce them?

**EDIT:**

I rebuild indexes and now the size is reduced to 1.7GB.